# Rails - Convert Mailchimp Response and store in JSONB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm using Gibbon to cache the lists that a particular user has in a JSONB format. I have 2 questions.

1. How do I convert the [response](http://pastebin.com/dqGCSGy7) some kind of array that I can store in the database. I've tried

   response.first.id

But I get the error that id is not a method.

2.What is the best way to store this data in a JSONB column?

Comment: Do you want to save entire response? if entire response no need to do anything you could save directly.

Comment: I just want to save the ID and Name of the list

Comment: You can take the value like this .. `response["lists"].first["id"]` and `response["lists"].first["name"]`

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the value like this .. `response["lists"].first["id"]` and `response["lists"].first["name"]`